# Exponential decay via spontaneous emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

Why does the exponential decay of the excited population of a two-level system (diagonal element $\rho_{ee}$ of the density matrix) into $\rho_{gg}$ (population of the ground state $\left|g\right>$) according to $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho_{ee}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho_{gg}=-\Gamma\rho_{ee}$ also enforce a decay of the coherence via $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho_{eg}=-\gamma_{ge}\rho_{ge}$ with $\gamma_{ge}\geq\frac{\Gamma}{2}$? How can I show this formally from avoiding the trace of $\rho$ to become greater than one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will not follow from the trace condition; more likely from positivity of $rho$.

Comment: Then something's wrong in my lecture slides. I will try to sort it out, thanks a lot.